# facebook php-graph-sdk v5 error on chrome

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api

I try to write a script facebook login. user php-graph-sdk v5. it works fine on firefox but not work on chrome and some others browser.

my login page index.php :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<a class="btn btn-facebook"  onclick="login_facebook();" href="javascript:void(0);">facebook login</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'app_id', // App ID
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    }

    function login_facebook()
    {
        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,picture,email', function(response) {
                    var email = response.email;
                    if(email != '')
                    {
                    //  alert(email);
                        window.location.replace('http://localhost/testphp/call-back.php');
                    }
                });
            } else 
            {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        },{scope: 'email,user_photos'});
    }
</script>
```

my call-back.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('Facebook/autoload.php');
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                  'app_id' => 'app_id', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
                  'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
                  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
                  ]);
            $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
try {
              $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
              echo $accessToken;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
              // When Graph returns an error
              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              // When validation fails or other local issues
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }

            if (! isset($accessToken)) {
              if ($helper->getError()) {
                header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
                echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
                echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
                echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
                echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
              } else {
                header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
                echo 'Bad request';
              }
              exit;
            }


            // Logged in
            // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
            $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

            // Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
            $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);

            // Get user’s Facebook ID
            $userId = $tokenMetadata->getField('user_id');

            try {
              // Get the Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
              // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
              $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name', $accessToken->getValue());
            //  print_r($response);
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
              // When Graph returns an error
              echo 'ERROR: Graph ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              // When validation fails or other local issues
              echo 'ERROR: validation fails ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }
            $me = $response->getGraphUser();
            //print_r($me);
            echo "Full Name: ".$me->getProperty('name')."<br>";
            echo "First Name: ".$me->getProperty('first_name')."<br>";
            echo "Last Name: ".$me->getProperty('last_name')."<br>";
            echo "Email: ".$me->getProperty('email');
            echo "Facebook ID: <a href='https://www.facebook.com/".$me->getProperty('id')."' target='_blank'>".$me->getProperty('id')."</a>";

?>
```

it works fine on firefox but chrome and some other browsers return error. Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\Helpers\FacebookJavaScriptHelper::getError() in call-back.php on line 24. can your plese help me about this error. Thanks!

Comment: This error happens on the server side, so the browser shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: The JavaScriptHelper object does not have a method getError. That you only see this server-side error in certain browsers, means that something went differently in those than in the others. You do not have a valid access token here, and that is why it goes into the if branch where you try to call a non-existing method. So you need to go figure out why you can get a valid token in some browsers, but not in others.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer my question. But on firefox. I get facebook token, chrome is not. So have any problem here?  Did you tru my code?